# [LibGDX][GWT] Error reading file skin.json in HTML [SerializationException]

Tags: java, json, node.js, gwt, libgdx

i'm having some problems deploying a libGDX project to HTML. I have a skin.json file to load basic GUI and Fonts. It work perfect on Android and Desktop but in HTML it doesn't. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Uncaught Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/skins/logo_and_font/logo_and_font.json
    at f_b.V$b [as jQ] (html-0.js:7370)
    at f_b.Y$b [as lQ] (html-0.js:7370)
    at f_b.b_b (html-0.js:5252)
    at f_b (html-0.js:1161)
    at Be (html-0.js:6955)
    at Ge (html-0.js:6136)
    at di (html-0.js:6583)
    at wh.xh [as Oc] (html-0.js:7361)
    at HTMLImageElement.eval (html-0.js:5881)
```

Here is my .json file that im trying to load:

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
    "green":{"a":1, "b":0, "g":1, "r":0},
    "white":{"a":1, "b":1, "g":1, "r":1},
    "red":{"a":1, "b":0, "g":0, "r":1 },
    "black":{"a":1, "b":0, "g":0, "r":0}
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont":{
    "default-font":{
      "file":"basic_font.fnt"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle":{
    "default":{
      "font":"default-font",
      "fontColor":"white"
    }
  }
}
```

If i remove the BitmatFont and LabelStyle block code it will load without any errors

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont":{
    "default-font":{
      "file":"basic_font.fnt"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle":{
    "default":{
      "font":"default-font",
      "fontColor":"white"
    }
  }
```

I have test it in Opera, Google Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. And the same error. So its not browser related. The game is being serve in a NodeJs server with express, but i also try it with Apache (XAMPP) and same problem, so don't think is server related. I have try with html:superDev and same problem too. I have remove the quotes from the json file and the same problem.

I load the .json file with asset manager here is the code of how i load it. I load it this way, cause im just loading the basic stuff needed to create a loading screen to then load others assets.

```
this.manager = new AssetManager();
this.assets = new ObjectMap<String, String>();

this.assets.put("logo_and_font_skin", "data/skins/logo_and_font/logo_and_font.json");
this.manager.load(this.assets.get("logo_and_font_skin"), Skin.class);
this.manager.finishLoading();
```

If i load it directly with `Gdx.files.internal("data/skins/logo_and_font/logo_and_font.json");` I get the same error.

In my *.gwt.xml files i have specified the class that are going to be reflected arcording to [libGDX Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection#gwt)

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont"/>
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label" />
```

The URI of the *.gwt.xml is the default one, but i have change to others and still get the same error. (Can't post the links cause i don't have enough reputation)

I compile the project with `gradlew.bat html:dist` it generated some files in /build/dist and those file are the one the i use to serve the game.

I think thats all i have try, maybe a few more thing but don't remember now. I have like 2 days in this or 3 day. It's my fisrt time deploying to a HTML with libGDX. Here is my environment:

- IDE: Android Studio 2.2.3
- libGDX Version: 1.9.5
- Gradle Version: 2.2.3
- GWT Version: 2.8.0
- JDK: 1.8.0

English is not my main language so if there some typos, sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your BitmapFont in your AssetManager that is referenced in your .json file.

Use finishLoading on the asset manager.
Get your BitmapFont from AssetManager.

```
BitmapFont x= manager.get(".....", BitmapFont.class);
```

Put that font into ObjectMap

```
ObjectMap<String, Object> font_map = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
font_map.put("nameOfFont", x);
```

Use SkinLoader and pass your dependency as parameter.

```
manager.load(skinPath, Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter(skinAtlas, font_map));
```

Answer (score 0):

@AbhishekAryan yes i try that and fail too. Thanks for the response anyway.

I keep testing with diferents way of loading the BitmapFont and always fail with an error. And i started thinking that maybe it was an error with libGDX, indeed it was, i updated libGDX to 1.9.6-SNAPSHOT and the problem was solve. I loaded the BitmapFont from my uiskin.json perfectly.

Comment: good, if you find your solution. It's better to find problem with 1.9.5 version and create an issue on github.